# Flutter remove item from list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

My question is about flutter's listview.

When I delete item from a list and set the state

```
setState(() { 
    items.removeAt(500);
});
```

flutter `listview.builder` scrolls to the top. I want it not to scroll after deleting item from the list.

What's your suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: its almost impossible to prevent scrolling top, cuz you redraw whole frame with setState, but unfortunately idk how to deal with it, you can try to get current scroll pixels then you remove the item navigate to same pixels that should work then

Comment: Can you be more specific? Add more code or describe your widget tree, fields etc.

Answer (score 0):

our widget tree is simple we creating list like

```
ListView.builder(
itemCount: messages.lenght,
itemBuilder: (ctx,index){
 return GestureDetector(
    onTap: (){
     showModalBottomSheet()... 
}
);
}
)
```

on bottom sheet there is a function calls setState() and delete item then ListView scrolls to top